# jquery TableSorter - How to rebuild or refresh drop down filters

Tags: filter, tablesorter

I am using "/*! TableSorter (FORK) v2.28.1 *//*"

I am using filters with the drop-down selection box.  Right now if you have multiple columns being filtered and you select one the other filter drop-down boxes do not get refreshed.  I had a customer complain about that.  Is there a way to have all the filter drop-down boxes get rebuilt when a filter is selected?

**Update**:

Thanks @mottie.  I wanted to show an example of my code to help clarify what I have.  Currently, it is not working.

I have a .net Gridview so to get the "filter-onlyAvail" on the TH, I have this (which does put it on the TH).

```
$("#<% =gvReport.ClientID %> thead th:nth-child(3)").attr('data-placeholder', 'All').addClass('filter-select filter-onlyAvail');
```

**Here is how I have my filter options set up**

```
 $("#<% =gvReport.ClientID %>").tablesorter({
            showProcessing: true,
            sortList: [[1, 0]],
            emptyTo: 'emptyMin',
            widgets: ["columns", "zebra", "filter", "Columns"],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_liveSearch: true,
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_childRows: true,
                filter_onlyAvail: 'filter-onlyAvail',
                filter_searchFiltered : true,
                filter_functions: {
                    2: true,
                    3: true,
                    4: true,
                    5: true,
                    7: true
                }
            },
            headers: {
                0: { filter: false },
                2: { sorter: 'digit' },
                6: { filter: false }
            },
            initialized: function () {
                ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Add a "filter-onlyAvail" class to the column - see the "discount" column in this demo - https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html

Comment: I added the "filter-onlyAvail" to the TH **<th class="filter-onlyAvail" scope="col" style="width:5em;">**   I also added **filter_onlyAvail: 'filter-onlyAvail',** to the "widgetOptions".  Is there anything else I am missing?